# Trying to write an SQL query with regexp_matches() look behind positive in postgresql

Tags: regex, postgresql, regex-lookarounds

From a PostgreSQL database, I'm trying to match 6 or more digits that come after a string that looks like "(OCoLC)" and I thought I had a working regular expression that would fit that description:

`(?<=\(ocolc\))[0-9]{6,}`

Here are some strings that it should return the digits for:

`|a(OCoLC)08507541` will return `08507541`

`|a(OCoLC)174097142` will return `174097142`

etc...

This seems to work to match strings when I test it on regex101.com, but when I incorporate it into my query:

```
SELECT
regexp_matches(v.field_content, '(?<=\(ocolc\))[0-9]{6,}', 'gi')

FROM
varfield as v

LIMIT 
1;
```

I get this message:

`ERROR:  invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid`

I'm not sure why it doesn't seem to like that expression.

**UPDATE**
I ended up just resorting to using a case statement, as that seemed to be the best way to work around this...

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN v.field_content ~* '\(ocolc\)[0-9]{6,}' 
    THEN (regexp_matches(v.field_content, '[0-9]{6,}', 'gi'))[1]
    ELSE v.field_content
END

FROM
varfield as v
```

as electricjelly noted, I'm *kind of* after just the numeric characters, but they have to be preceded by the "(OCoLC)" string, or they're not exactly what I'm after. This is part of a larger query, so I'm running a second case statement a boolean flag in cases where the start of the string wasn't "(OCoLC)". These seems to be more helpful anyway, as I'm going to probably want to preserve those other values somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like after doing some more searching, this is only a feature of versions of PostgreSQL server >= `9.6`

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CONSTRAINTS-TABLE

The version I am running is version `9.4.6`

https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/E1ZsIsY-0006z6-6T@gemulon.postgresql.org

So, the answer is it's not available for this version of PostgreSQL, but presumably this would work just fine in the latest version of the server.

Comment: have you tried regex_replace instead? it seems to work for your version of pgsql, and while the functionality is different, it might accomplish the same goal

Comment: @electricjelly actually, the look ahead / behind not being an option might have been a blessing in disguise. I decided that running a case statements to determine if the string has (OCoLC) in it, might be the best option.

Answer (score 2):

After looking over your question it seems your error is caused from a syntax problem, not so much from the function not being available on your version of PostgreSQl, as I tested it on 9.6 and I received the same error.

However, what you seem to want is to pull the numbers from a given field as in

`|a(OCoLC)08507541` becomes `08507541`

an easy way you could accomplish this would be to use regex_replace

the function would be:

`regexp_replace('table.field', '\D', '', 'g')`

the `\D` in the function finds all non-numbers and replaces it with a nothing (hence the `''`) and returns everything else

Comment: Sometimes the fields contain things that aren't "(OCoLC)" in front of the number, so returning just the number wouldn't exactly be correct. For example, if the field's string was "|a(Sirsi) o12369282"

Comment: is every prefix (like that of `(OCoLC)` or `(Sirsi)` always the same length? otherwise you would need to use a if/then or a case in order to accomplish what you want, because the regex would work in one place but not the other, either that or you would have to use some very complicated regex.

Comment: I don't think that it's always going to be the same fixed length of characters before the number unfortunately. I'll updated the original post to maybe give a better explanation of my case statement. Thanks again for all your help!